# Try block starts printing while printStackTrace method is Printing

Tags: java, exception, printing, stack-trace

```
public class Argon {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Basil basil = new Basil();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            try {
                System.out.println("Please enter a number!");
                String num1 = in.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please enter another number!");
                String num2 = in.nextLine();
                basil.numberCruncher(num1, num2);
                System.out.println(basil.getSum());
                break;
            } catch (NumberException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        } while (true);

    }

}
```

The code above works tries a block of code and catches any errors that occur. I purposefully supplied an error and the code prints the following.

```
Please enter a number!
nop
Please enter another number!
w
NumberException: Your Program Went Bananas.
Please enter a number!
    at Basil.numberCruncher(Basil.java:23)
    at Argon.main(Argon.java:15)
```

The Stack Trace has not been fully printed, but the try block starts executing anyways.
Why does this occur and what could I do to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Throwable#printStackTrace` prints to `System.err` by default. You're printing to `System.out`. Since there's only one console, it receives both of those streams.

Whatever controls the console you see must be doing its own buffering and flushing which does not synchronize the writes from each stream and that can cause mixed output even though the program executed sequentially.

Comment: Is there any why to change that buffering, or could I print to another console?

Comment: @CaptainCloud You can use `System.setErr(PrintStream)` to redirect output to a different location.